# Transfer history from firefox to chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, export, import

This might sound like a silly question but i'd like to transfer all my history (specifically links i clicked on) from firefox to chrome. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean your bookmarks?

Comment: @Phoenix I think he means History, its very clear from my view.

Comment: @Simon - indeed, he did explicitly say "history". I've had to sadly navigate a lot of users (in real life) that are very prone to say anything but what they really mean. Seems like a rare occurrence on superuser, thankfully.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Transferring the history is possible. Here are some easy steps to do so which i got from [here](http://www.dkszone.net/import-firefox-bookmarks-passwords-chrome):

1. Go to Tools (the wrench icon) –> Options.
2. Go to the ‘Personal Stuff’ tab and click on ‘Import data from another browser…’ in the Browsing data section.
3. Select Firefox from the list of browsers, and then click Import. Unselect any of the check boxes for Favorites/Bookmarks, Search Engines, Saved passwords, or Browsing history if you do not want to import it.

After that, you should have all your settings, including browsing history. I have not tested this, so I will now and then modify my answer if necessary.

Comment: I did not expect it to be that easy (nor use chrome much)

Comment: Chrome seem very user friendly for these things, and easy to find stuff. Maybe its time for me to take a look at it

Comment: I'm on Chrome 86 and currently you got to **'Settings' -> 'You and Google' -> 'Import bookmarks and settings'**. What wasn't obvious here is that you don't need to do any kind of export from Firefox - Chrome handles all of that.

Comment: With this, I transferred history from one Firefox profile to Chrome, and then from Chrome to another Firefox profile. since Firefox doesn't provide a way to do it.  :D

Answer (score 6):

Transferring history, bookmarks and other things are easy.
Go to Chrome

1. Type "chrome://settings/importData" in url.
2. Then choose what you need to transfer and import.

After that, you should have all your settings, including browsing history and all.

[image]

Comment: Can confirm this still works in Chrome 86