# Migrating from firefox quantum to chrome:

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, data-migration, firefox-quantum

So when firefox quantum came out I was torn from my normal happy chrome-user life and stuck in-between two browsers for about 6 months or so:

I'm sick of this kind of life. I want all my data and history in chrome, so that I can keep track of it all via my google account, and since chrome is the browser on my phone, tracking my activity on chrome and via google is much much easier.

please help me, I've tried:
[Transfer history from firefox to chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/306262/transfer-history-from-firefox-to-chrome)

but it doesn't offer me the option to import from firefox quantum. It only offers IE and edge, I don't know why, I use windows 10.

What I'd ideally like is to have all my data: including bookmarks, autofills, browser history and saved passwords moved into chrome and added to the existing data on chrome.

PS: since it offers all data with IE, maybe we could consider Quantum->IE->Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (*for bookmarks only*):

1. Open up Firefox
2. Hit `Ctrl+Shift+B`
3. Go to: `Import and Backup`, then: `Export Bookmarks to HTML`
4. Open up Chrome
5. Head to `chrome://bookmarks/`
6. From menu, select `Import bookmarks`
7. Select exported HTML (*step #3*)